# Symfony2 input group form label

Tags: symfony, twig

```
{{ form_label(form.heapStartDate, '',{'label_attr': {'class': 'form-label'}}) }}
<div class="input-group form-group col-lg-12">
{{ form_widget(form.heapStartDate, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control datepicker ', 'placeholder': 'HEAP Start date','data-toggle':'tooltip','title':'Home Energy Asss. Program start date','data-placement':'top'}}) }}
<label for="ess_customerbundle_customer_heapStartDate" class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
</label>
</div>
{{ form_errors(form.heapStartDate) }}
```

I am using static value for "label for" attribute. I want it to be dynamic. How to get value of label only in twig?a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
<label for="{{ form.heapStartDate.vars.id }}" class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
```